# Sandboxing prl_disp_service to prevent disk waking

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, parallels-desktop

So there is prl_disp_service, a Parallels 7 background service that periodically wakes the internal hard drive in my Macbook Pro although it`s unmounted most of the time since I boot from an SSD I replaced the DVD drive with.

For reference: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=114974

Is there a way to apply some sandbox-exec profile to this process so it will continue functioning normally but won´t see /dev/disk1* and do stat or something else on it that causes it to wake up?

Comment: When I'm not using Parallels, I'm stopping all it's services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay, I managed to sandbox prl_disp_service \o/

I put a file named prl_disp_service.sb into /Library/Sandbox/Profiles denying ioctl on disk1 (the harddisk I wanted to prevent from waking):

```
(version 1)
(allow default)
(debug deny)
(import "system.sb")
(deny file-read* file-ioctl
    (regex "/dev/disk1*"))
```

And edited /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Resources/ParallelsDispatcherService:

```
sandbox-exec -f /Library/Sandbox/Profiles/prl_disp_service.sb "${ParallelsDispatcherService}" -e --logfile "${LogFile}" --pidfile "${PidFile}" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```